# Calculation for discount price not showing up as a number in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a form that updates ticket prices based on day and time selected, where on certain days it will be discounted and the other days it will not.

As far as pricing of tickets is concerned, I've been using HTML to store and manipulate the values, like so:

```
<tr>
    <td>Adult</td>
        <td>
            <select class="qty" name="SA">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="text" value="18.00" class="price" readonly>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="amount">$0.00</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**How it works**

- The quantity `value` is selected based on whatever drop-down option the user selects.
- The quantity value is then multiplied by the price, which is stored in the `value` in the `<input>` HTML, in this case it's 18.
- The `<span>` is then updated with the result, showing the subtotal price.
- Note: I have multiple more sections of `<tr>` that are identical to this one

**JS/jquery used for calculation**

```
    //price of seating
function calculatePrice() {

    var time = $("#whichSession").val(); // sets time to value
    var day = $("#whichDay").val(); // sets day to value

    var sum = 0;

    $('#bookingTable > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
        var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        var amount = (qty * price)
        sum += amount;
        $(this).find('.amount').text('$' + amount.toFixed(2));
    });
    //just update the total to sum  
    $('#totalprice').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Another user has suggested that I create a new function that updates the `value` of the price in real-time so that it can get the appropriate discount values.

**JS/jquery used for calculating discount prices**

```
// calls get price function on day change
$('.qty').change(function () {
    getPrices();
});

// sets value of price based on day and time
function getPrices ( day, time ) {  
  if ( day=='mon' || day == 'tue' || time=='1pm' ) {
    prices = {SA:12, SP:10, SC:8, FA:25, FC:20, B1:20, B2:20, B3:20}
  } else {
    prices = {SA:18, SP:15, SC:12, FA:30, FC:25, B1:30, B2:30, B3:30}
  }
  return prices;
}
```

**My issue**

When I use `alert` to show what value it's actually changing it to, it seems to be the correct one. However, it prints as '$NaN' in the `span` which is meant to show the subtotal amount for each ticket.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xrj7jof/4/)

I've created a fiddle so you guys can see how the whole thing works. Please excuse if any of the code is dodgy. It works a lot better when it's actually on my website.

Sorry for the long post. I just wanted to make sure I was being extremely clear with my issue. Please let me know if anything is unclear and I'll try to clarify.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that specific person type need to be used to access the correct price.
You may need to read its value as shown below:

```
$('#bookingTable > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
  var type= $(this).find('select:first').attr('name');
  var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  var amount = (qty * price[type])
  sum += amount;

  $(this).find('.amount').text('$' + amount.toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. What I need to do is get the value of each price <input> to be updated based on the conditions in the `getPrices` function.

Comment: Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xrj7jof/5/). Do you mean to update prices displayed on `$('#whichDay').change(..)` ?

Comment: Nono. Update the value of `<input type="text" value="18.00" class="price" readonly>`. Because my original price calculation was `qty * price` and the `price` was based on that value. If I could get the value of that to be updated, then it will SHOW the correct price (your updated fiddle calculates the correct price but doesnt show it) AND calculate it correctly as well.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xrj7jof/7/). This is what I've tried so far with no results. I added the `setPrice()` function.

Comment: You are welcome. There was some debugging fun, but we did it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function `getPrices()` is returning a JavaScript object and not a number.

So if you do:

```
var amount = (qty * prices.SP);
```

instead of:

```
var amount = (qty * price);
```

Your amount is a Number and you can do Math operations on it

Comment: The problem is, it's not always going to be 'SP'. Which object it returns basically depends on what the user has selected. Would something like `price.prices` work?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was, it's meant to change the price of ALL the tickets based on day/time selected. If I do `prices.SP` it will change all the price of tickets to that amount only.

Comment: You probably just need to add a 3rd parameter for your function getPrices(day, time, userSelection), then this function could return the individual price only instead of the whole object.

Comment: Makes sense. I've got an idea, but, is it possible to have a function within a function?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to save your initial selection in a variable and then use $.each to iterate through prices, which is the issue (it being an object).  Here's a modified code from your JSFiddle:

```
var subTotals = $('#bookingTable > tbody  > tr');
var index = 0;
$.each(prices,function (key,value) {
    var qty = subTotals.eq(index).find('option:selected').val();
    var amount = (qty * value)

    alert(amount);
    sum += amount;

    subTotals.eq(index++).find('.amount').text('$' + amount.toFixed(2));
});
```

Hope this help.